# getHue from .accentColor swiftui always returns blue hsb values

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a make a gradient background, which takes the current .accentColor and modifies its HSB values into a newValue to be the endPoint.
The accentColor when called returns the default blue, instead of the current red color.

```
struct Graph: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GraphView()
        }.accentColor(.red)
    }
}

private struct GraphView: View {
    var enhancedAccentColor: Color {
        var (h, s, b, a): (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        UIColor(Color.accentColor).getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)

        let color = UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: b, alpha: a)
        return Color(color)
    }

    var gradient: Gradient { Gradient(colors: [.accentColor,
                                               enhancedAccentColor]) }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 400)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient,
                                         startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0),
                                         endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)))
            )
    }
}
```

The enhancedAccentColor works fine when using other preset Color values.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? This doesn't compile

Comment: I have changed the code, so it's compileable without my other code. If the accentcolor were to give the current value, the view should return a solid red color

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to the “real” accent color. Depending on what you want to do to the accent color, I might be able to suggest other ways to get the same visual effect. But you didn't explain what effect you want.

`Color.accentColor` returns a special placeholder representing the accent color:

```swift
  1> import SwiftUI
  2> print(Color.red)
red
  3> print(Color.accentColor)
AccentColorProvider()
```

When it's time to actually fill in pixels with the accent color, SwiftUI looks looks up the current accent color based on `accentColor` modifiers, asset catalogs, the color scheme, etc.

But when you're creating your `UIColor`, it's not pixel-filling time, so SwiftUI hasn't set up the mechanism for getting the correct accent color. You get the default accent color instead.

The `accentColor` modifier stores the accent color in the environment. It's defined like this:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension View {
  @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
  @inlinable public func accentColor(_ accentColor: SwiftUI.Color?) -> some SwiftUI.View {
        return environment(\.accentColor, accentColor)
    }
  
}
```

But unfortunately, Apple doesn't think you deserve access to that environment property. The `accentColor` property is declared like this:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension EnvironmentValues {
  @usableFromInline
  internal var accentColor: SwiftUI.Color? {
    get
    set
  }
}
```

Because it's declared `internal`, you can't use it.

#### UPDATE

> What i am trying to accomplish is for the gradient to start with the accentColor and end with the accentColor with a lower saturation.

Perhaps you can get a satisfactory effect by using this modifier:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func saturationFade(_ amount: Double) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            self
                .saturation(amount)
                .mask(
                    LinearGradient(
                        colors: [.clear, .white],
                        startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom
                    )
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("hello")
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 80)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color.accentColor)
                .saturationFade(0.5)
        )
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    HStack(spacing: 8) {
        ExampleView()
            .accentColor(.red)

        ExampleView()
            .accentColor(.green)


        ExampleView()
            .accentColor(.orange)
    }
)
```

Result:

[image: three rounded rectangles showing fades from red, green, and orange to partially desaturated red, green, and orange]

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is for the gradient to start with the accentColor and end with the accentColor with a lower saturation. I am using accentColor as it is easy to set the color theme of the app

Comment: Works as a nice alternative. Thank you :)

Comment: @robmayoff Maybe there is some kind of caching implemented within Apple's private code? See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69435504/292145

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine for me without any changes as of Xcode 13.0 (13A233).

**BUT:** I found out that `Color.accentColor` is always returning the default blue color if you read the color values "too early".

```
@main
struct AccentColorTestApp: App {
    init() {
        // By adding these two lines your example stops working
        // and draws a solid blue rectangle:

        var (h, s, b, a): (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        UIColor(Color.accentColor).getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GraphView()
        }
    }
}
```

I have the same issue of loosing my custom accent color when starting Microsoft's [AppCenter](https://install.appcenter.ms/users/qlaas/apps/vesta-paint/distribution_groups/vestapaintpublic%20https://install.appcenter.ms/users/qlaas/apps/vesta-paint/distribution_groups/vestapaintpublic) too early.